Script doesn't recognize HTML file name
I am working through Google Sheets and Google App Script.
I am trying to access an HTML file called "Send Grades" through a script. This works fine...
var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Send Grades");

But this does not work...
console.log(email[i][1]); = Send Grades
var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('"' + email[i][1] + '"');

This is the error - 10:07:03 AM Error
Exception: No HTML file named "Send Grades" was found.
I tried using different quotes and tildes but nothing has worked.
What am I doing wrong?

The quotes aren't part of the name; they are used in the first example to indicate the beginning & end of the string holding the name, which isn't needed when that string is coming from a variable.

The value in email[i][1] is already a string, have you tried without manually adding additional quotation marks to the string?  For example, var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile( email[i][1] );

"I tried using different quotes and tildes but nothing has worked. What am I doing wrong?" - What you're doing wrong is using different quotes and tildes.  If email[i][1] contains the value you want to use then just use it.  It looks like you're simply misunderstanding what a string is in JavaScript, which is little more than a typo.
